# Tokio Codec. Cannot decode multiple frames sent

Tags: rust, rust-tokio

The problem I am having with framed read is that whenever I send two frames in a go, the codec reads the two frames as if they are one. My Implementation is

```rust
  async fn handle(connection: Connection) -> Result<(), SyntheticError> {
    let mut framed = Framed::new(connection.stream, SyntheticFrameCodec::new());
    let mode = Mode::Unauthenticated;
    framed
      .send(SyntheticFrame::ServerGreeting(ServerGreetingFrame::with_mode(mode)))
      .await?;
    // I should be able to different frames and get it decoded.
    framed
      .send(SyntheticFrame::SetUpResponse(SetupResponseFrame::with_mode(mode)))
      .await?;

    while let Some(message) = framed.next().await {
      match message {
        Ok(bytes) => println!("bytes: {:?}", bytes),
        Err(err) => Err(err)?,
      }
    }

    Ok(())
  }
```

on the reciever end, my implementation is

```rust
  pub async fn connect() -> Result<(), SyntheticError> {
    let addr = "127.0.0.1:9000".parse::<SocketAddr>().unwrap();
    let stream = TcpStream::connect(addr).await?;
    let mut framed = SyntheticFrameCodec::new().framed(stream);

    while let Some(frame) = framed.next().await {
      match frame {
        Ok(f) => debug!("Recieved Frame: {:?}", f),
        Err(err) => Err(err)?,
      }
    };
    Ok(())
  }
```

When I send one frame, I am okay, but two frames in succession, The code panics because it tries to read two frames in succession. The frames I am sending are of different size

Using Wireshark, I can confirm that the two frames are being seperately.

Comment: What is `SyntheticFrameCodec`? I can't find any type by that name in a web search. It might help to specify all of the libraries you are using (share your `Cargo.toml` and `use`s)

Comment: It is a custom codec ... After digging through, my codec was the problem as i was not using any delimiting